# Remove 1000Hz tone from FFT array in C

Tags: c, audio, fft, wav

I have an array of doubles which is the result of the FFT applied on an array, that contains the audio data of a Wav audio file in which i have added a 1000Hz tone.

I obtained this array thought the DREALFT defined in "Numerical Recipes".(I must use it).
(The original array has a length that is power of two.)

Mine array has this structure:

array[0] = first real valued component of the complex transform

array[1] = last real valued component of the complex transform

array[2] = real part of the second element

array[3] = imaginary part of the second element

etc......

Now, i know that this array represent the frequency domain.

I want to determine and kill the 1000Hz frequency.

I have tried this formula for finding the index of the array which should contain the 1000Hz frequency:

```
index = 1000. * NElements /44100;
```

Also, since I assume that this index refers to an array with real values only, i have determined the correct(?) position in my array, that contains imaginary values too:

```
    int correctIndex=2;

for(k=0;k<index;k++){
    correctIndex+=2;
}
```

(I know that surely there is a way easier but it is the first that came to mind)

Then, i find this value: 16275892957.123705, which i suppose to be the real part of the 1000Hz frequency.(Sorry if this is an imprecise affermation but at the moment I do not care to know more about it)

So i have tried to suppress it:

```
array[index]=-copy[index]*0.1f;
```

I don't know exactly why i used this formula but is the only one that gives some results, in fact the 1000hz tone appears to decrease slightly.

This is the part of the code in question:

```
    double *copy = malloc( nCampioni * sizeof(double));
    int nSamples;

 /*...Fill copy with audio data...*/

     /*...Apply ZERO PADDING and reach the length of 8388608 samples, 
 or rather 8388608 double values...*/


/*Apply the FFT (Sure this works)*/
drealft(copy - 1, nSamples, 1);

/*I determine the REAL(?) array index*/
i= 1000. * nSamples /44100;

/*I determine MINE(?) array index*/
int j=2;

for(k=0;k<i;k++){
    j+=2;
}

/*I reduce the array value, AND some other values aroud it as an attempt*/
for(i=-12;i<12;i+=2){
    copy[j-i]=-copy[i-j]*0.1f;
    printf("%d\n",j-i);
}

/*Apply the inverse FFT*/
drealft(copy - 1, nSamples, -1);

/*...Write the audio data on the file...*/
```

NOTE: for simplicity I omitted the part where I get an array of double from an array of int16_t

How can i determine and totally kill the 1000Hz frequency?

Thank you!

Comment: `drealft(copy - 1, nSamples, 1);` why the `- 1`? This seems wrong.

Comment: NO it's correct, it's a known problem of the Numerical Recipes algorithm in C! Thank you!

Comment: `copy[j-i]=-copy[i-j]*0.1f;` if you have `j == 2` at first iterationm you end up with `copy[-10] = -copy[-14]*0.1f;` this will not be pretty. So just as a safety check, you want to make sure that `j - i` does not give you an out of bound index. Also I suspect you inadvertently inverted `j-i` into `i-j` in the right handside.

Comment: Thank you very much, i corrected it!!! But unfortunately the final result does not change!!

Comment: Note that unless the desired frequency (1000 Hz) lines up precisely with an FFT bin centre, then its energy will not appear in a single bin; instead it will be spread across all bins, so modifying a single bin will not "remove" it.

Comment: Note also that even if it does line up exactly, it will appear at **two** bins, one at 1000*N/44100, and another at N - 1000*N/44100.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: `drealft` returns only half of the FFT; the other half is symmetric (complex conjugate) and would not fit in the N elements of the real array that is used for output.

Comment: Wow, changing the two bins it happens a strange thing: the beginning of the file is PERFECT, the tone is suppressed, but it is still present in the rest of the file

Comment: @Eric, You are right! I forgot this thing, so, mine seems to be only a random result

Comment: I **strongly** encourage you to consider time-domain techniques. I realize that you may be required to do it this way, but for anyone else looking at this question for advice http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/why-eq-is-done-in-time-domain.html

Comment: Ut has to be said, a DFT makes for a very poor band-pass filter - for the reasons outlined in @EricPostpischil's answer below, and also because of the computational load of a forward and inverse DFT.   You're much better of doing this in the time domain.

Comment: @BjornRoche: There's a few potentially misleading things in that blog post.  For example, the "pre-echo" is not an FFT problem, it's simply the implication of using a linear-phase filter (the only alternative is frequency-dependent phase-shift!).  Also, the latency you get from an FFT would be essentially the same as the group delay you get from the equivalent time-domain filter.

Comment: Thanks Oli, I will update the post.

Comment: Looking back at this, Oli, I actually covered this. eg, I said "[FIR filters [implemented in the time domain] suffer from many of the problems mentioned above including pre-echo, high computational cost and latency, but they do have some acoustical properties that make them desirable in some applications."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Oli Charlesworth writes, because your target frequency is not exactly one of the FFT bins (your `index`, TargetFrequency * NumberOfElements / SamplingRate, is not exactly an integer), the energy of the target frequency will be spread across all bins. For a start, you can eliminate some of the frequency by zeroing the bin closest to the target frequency. This will of course affect other frequencies somewhat too, since it is slightly off target. To better suppress the target frequency, you will need to consider a more sophisticated filter.

However, for educational purposes: To suppress the frequency corresponding to a bin, simply set that bin to zero. You must set both the real and the imaginary components of the bin to zero, which you can do with:

```
copy[index*2 + 0] = 0;
copy[index*2 + 1] = 1;
```

Some notes about this:

You had this code to calculate the position in the array:

```
int correctIndex = 2;
for (k = 0; k < index; k++) {
    correctIndex += 2;
}
```

That is equivalent to:

```
correctIndex = 2*(index+1);
```

I believe you want `2*index`, not `2*(index+1)`. So you were likely reducing the wrong bin.

At one point in your question, you wrote `array[index] = -copy[index]*0.1f;`. I do not know what `array` is. You appeared to be working in place in `copy`. I also do not know why you multiplied by 1/10. If you want to eliminate a frequency, just set it to zero. Multiplying it by 1/10 only reduces it to 10% of its original magnitude.

I understand that you must pass `copy-1` to `drealft` because the Numerical Recipes code uses one-based indexing. However, the C standard does not support the way you are doing it. The behavior of the expression `copy-1` is not defined by the standard. It will work in most C implementations. However, to write supported portable code, you should do this instead:

```
// Allocate one extra element.
double *memory = malloc((nCampioni+1) * sizeof *memory);

// Make a pointer that is convenient for your work.
double *copy = memory+1;

…

// Pass the necessary base address to drealft.
drealft(memory, nSamples, 1);

// Suppress a frequency.
copy[index*2 + 0] = 0;
copy[index*2 + 1] = 0;

…

// Free the memory.
free(memory);
```

One experiment I suggest you consider is to initialize an array with just a sine wave at the desired frequency:

```
for (i = 0; i < nSamples; ++i)
    copy[i] = sin(TwoPi * Frequency / SampleRate * i);
```

(`TwoPi` is of course `2*3.1415926535897932384626433`.) Then apply `drealft` and look at the results. You will see that much of the energy is at a peak in the closest bin to the target frequency, but much of it has also spread to other bins. Clearly, zeroing a single bin and performing the inverse FFT cannot eliminate all of the frequency. Also, you should see that the peak is in the same bin you calculated for `index`. If it is not, something is wrong.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I followed some of your suggestion and now my program works perfectly. Also i have opportunely zeroed the bin closest to the target frequency and the file sound as the original.